# How this very famous method of "continuous image of the light ray" trick came into existence?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, history

[image]Consider a setup of a two mirrors subtending an angle theta with respect to each other and length being $d$. Now consider a light ray which is being projected at angle alpha from the line of angle bisector of that line $l$ distance ($d>l$) away from the meeting point of the two mirrors. Problem was to find how many reflections does the light do so and the minimum distance the light is from meeting point.

There was a very famous method of considering light ray reflection as image of the ray about the mirror where it's being strucked and continuously carrying it out. So as to get the path to be a straight line and minimum distance being the perpendicular distance of this line from the meeting point. I would like to know who thought of this method and the process behind getting this amazing method to solve such problem, the early progress which lead to this great method of reducing such a difficult problem to such degree of easiness.

Comment: sounds like a question for history of science. https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Posting a diagram which identifies your $\alpha$ and $\theta$ as well as the length $l$ would be very helfpul.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be moved to HSM.stackexchange

Comment: Ok sure i am sending a figure

Comment: @CarlWitthoft dont need to close it , it just need to move so why close ?